# Building Oracle XE docker image in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: oracle, windows, docker

I'm trying to install Oracle XE 18c in a docker container in Windows 10. I have docker already installed, and I need to build the image as explained [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/deliver-oracle-database-18c-express-edition-in-containers).

I cloned the git repository, but I'm stuck on this step, as what I cloned are Linux commands and not Windows.

After cloning with:

```
git clone https://github.com/oracle/docker-images.git
```

If I `cd` to `docker-images\OracleDatabase\SingleInstance\dockerfiles\18.4.0` to build the image I see the following `sh` comands, instead of `exe` or `bat`:

```
12/28/2019  01:36 PM             1,137 checkDBStatus.sh
12/28/2019  01:36 PM               905 checkSpace.sh
12/28/2019  01:36 PM                75 Checksum.xe
12/28/2019  01:36 PM             2,752 Dockerfile.xe
12/28/2019  01:36 PM               533 oracle-xe-18c.conf
12/28/2019  01:36 PM             6,132 runOracle.sh
12/28/2019  01:36 PM               775 setPassword.sh
```

How to build this image in Windows?

Comment: What's your Docker environment?. Docker Desktop or Docker Toolbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Wsl Ubuntu Bash set path to Docker executables or simply install Git Bash for Windows from Docker Tools and run the shell script from Git Bash terminal(I prefer Git Bash).Download and Copy Oracle18xe rpm file to 18.40 folder

This is output from Git Bash for windows

```
 xxx@localhost MINGW64 /d/docker-images/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0 (master)                                                                                                                                                                                              
    $ ls -lrt
    total 2513906
    -rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121         74 Dec 28 13:17 Checksum.xe
    -rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121       2675 Dec 28 13:17 Dockerfile.xe
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121       1137 Dec 28 13:17 checkDBStatus.sh*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121        905 Dec 28 13:17 checkSpace.sh*
    -rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121        533 Dec 28 13:17 oracle-xe-18c.conf
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121       6132 Dec 28 13:17 runOracle.sh*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 user 197121        775 Dec 28 13:17 setPassword.sh*
    -rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 2574155124 Dec 28 13:48 oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

After running shell script successfully

```
xxx@localhost MINGW64 /d/docker-images/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0 (master)
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
oracle/database     18.4.0-xe           19b38be42ae6        30 minutes ago      8.44GB
oraclelinux         7-slim              0d49b70bc432        9 days ago          118MB

xxx@localhost MINGW64 /d/docker-images/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles (master)
$ docker run --name myxedb \
>     -d \
>     -p 51521:1521 \
>     -p 55500:5500 \
>     -e ORACLE_PWD=xxxxxxx \
>     -e ORACLE_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8 \
>     oracle/database:18.4.0-xe


xxx@localhost MINGW64 /d/docker-images/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0 (master)
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                             PORTS                                                        NAMES
afce013adb98        oracle/database:18.4.0-xe   "/bin/sh -c 'exec $O…"   19 seconds ago      Up 16 seconds (health: starting)   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:51521->1521/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55500->5500/tcp   myxedb
```

You can connect to database via sqlplus or login into docker container using Windows Dos

```
    D:\>docker exec -it --user=oracle myxedb bash


[oracle@afce013adb98 /]$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [XE] ?
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /opt/oracle



[oracle@afce013adb98 /]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

    SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Dec 29 05:04:32 2019
    Version 18.4.0.0.0

    Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
    Version 18.4.0.0.0

    SQL> select banner from v$version;

    BANNER
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

> P.S:-Make sure you logged into docker hub from git bash terminal
>   `docker login`

**To use WSL subsystem bash terminal add path and alias to .bashrc**

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:/mnt/c/Program\Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:$PATH"
alias docker=docker.exe
alias docker-compose=docker-compose.exe
```

From WSL Bash terminal

```
xxxx@localhost:~# docker -v
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. I downloaded the rpm, checked the sha-256 and put it in 18.4.0 directory, but when running the shell script I get `md5sum: 'oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm'$'\r': No such file or directory`. The file name is correct, what's wrong?

Comment: Yes that's correct one.Are you running the command `./buildDockerImage.sh -v 18.4.0 -x` (it should be x at the end for Express edition).Work around is comment out validate packages in shell script.

Comment: adding `-i` to ignore the check sum worked

Comment: Yes I realized that after posting that comment :-)

Comment: can you take a look at [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259850/cannot-dump-database-in-oracle-on-docker)? thanks

Comment: I have tried to use bash, but buildDockerImage.sh does not see docker (`bash buildDockerImage.sh -v 12.2.0.1 -s` => `docker: command not found`), even though i added it to PATH.

Comment: @Alexander Edited answer just add path and alias and run the command `docker -v`

Comment: @Kumar yes. Well, it wasn’t obvious for me, because manual was about running sh script via Windows powershell - but it turned out I had to install docker package for Ubuntu as well - previously installed Windows docker desktop app was not enough. After this I had to run docker as host (also not obvious step) and then I finally moved further and Oracle installation begun. Though, it was not successful, because probably some 1000th line of some script failed and eventually I gave up: as usual, stuff for Linux is too complex for ordinary people

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would really recommend using WSL or rather WSL 2 for Docker now.

But there is another (easier?) way to build you Oracle 18c Docker image with the official Dockerfiles (you might even use this way from inside WSL/ WSL2 if you see a need for this).

Do note that the (Linux/Bash) script buildDockerImage.sh is just a helper (checking the checksum and so on) building the command to call docker. You can build your image directly with the available Dockerfile, ie. Dockerfile.xe (in the case of 18.0.4).

From within the folder "18.4.0" (where you have also saved the database (Linux-Version!) downloaded from Oracle) enter:

```
docker build -t [image name of your choosing] -f Dockerfile.xe .
```

[be sure to include the . (dot) at the end because this tells docker "this folder"]

Do note that this takes roughly 40-50 minutes. I have done it this way (before WSL 2) and it worked for me quite well.

HTH
Andreas